# Line spacing 18 pt in r markdown

Tags: r-markdown, line-spacing

Iam writing my thesis in r markdown and want to change the line spacing to 18 pt. But i cant find a solution for it. I only found the setting for onehalf spacing or 1.5 spacing but no for exactly some arbitrary pt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output format is PDF, you can add

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{leading}
  - \leading{18pt}
```

to your YAML headers. Or just the LaTeX code to a preamble file you are including anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[`linestretch`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#layout) is the YAML directive for that.

With all the power and caveats that [\setstretch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184933/setspace-fine-tuning-or-an-alternative-for-scrbook) brings I guess, if you are looking for a specific physical size.